# Trying to deploy hyper ledger fabric framework using python

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

Hello I am trying to deploy a smart contract (chain code) project for master thesis using hyper ledger fabric with python.

so I try to setup a fabric network using the below

```
$ HLF_VERSION=1.4.6
$ docker pull hyperledger/fabric-peer:${HLF_VERSION}
$ docker pull hyperledger/fabric-orderer:${HLF_VERSION}
$ docker pull hyperledger/fabric-ca:${HLF_VERSION}
$ docker pull hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:${HLF_VERSION}
```

which of course downloads required images to my docker for use

Next I run the below

```
$ docker-compose -f test/fixtures/docker-compose-2orgs-4peers-tls.yaml up
```

but then I run into the below error

```
WARN[0000] The "HLF_VERSION" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "HLF_VERSION" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "HLF_VERSION" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "HLF_VERSION" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "HLF_VERSION" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
Error response from daemon: no such image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:: invalid reference format
```

I did some search online with regards to the error and I saw some recommendations like below

like running this first "export IMAGE_TAG=latest" before running the docker compose command

but I'm still unable to pass this stage, please I need help on this.

I am a novice on this please, I am just interested in expanding my knowledge on block chain using my master thesis.

Thanks

Comment: https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric/topic/32054206

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by

recreating my .env file in both my "test" and "fixtures" directories

Followed by export the image latest command as below

```
export IMAGE_TAG=latest
```

and then the initial command which initially triggered the error

```
docker-compose -f test/fixtures/docker-compose-2orgs-4peers-tls.yaml up
```

credit to this page:
https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric/topic/32054206